# Looking to export JSON in Python using multiple nested blocks

Tags: python

I am trying to build out a JSON export mirrored on this example:

```
import json

data = {}
data['people'] = []
data['people'].append({
    'name': 'Scott',
    'website': 'stackabuse.com',
    'from': 'Nebraska'
})

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

However, I wish for there to be more nested {} than just the one above, but cannot seem to figure out how to do that. This is what I'd like the JSON to look like:

```
{
   "people":{
      "Citizens":{
         "Workers":{
            "wage":"34",
            "id":"1 of 2"
         },
         "non-workers":{
            "wage":"0",
            "id":"2 of 2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your code is only related to your desired output in that they both have the key "people".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the method **Brenden Price** pointed out works, there is no need for so many statements. The number of statements solely depends on how deep the dictionaries which you are assigning are.

At its shortest:

```py
data = {}
data["people"] = {
    "Citizens": {
        "Workers": {"wage": "34", "id": "1 of 2"},
        "Non-Workers": {"wage": "0", "id": "2 of 2"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the nested {}, you're adding more dictionaries. I'm not sure the goal of this, but o achieve that exact example you've provided, your code would be something along the lines of this:

```
data = {}
data['people'] = {} # empty dict of people
data['people']['citizens'] = {} # empty dict of workers inside people
data['people']['citizens']['workers'] = {} # empty dict of workers inside people
data['people']['citizens']['non-workers'] = {} # empty dict of non-workers inside people
data['people']['citizens']['workers']['wage'] = "34" # set workers wage to str "34"
data['people']['citizens']['workers']['id'] = "1 of 2" # set id to str "1 of 2"
data['people']['citizens']['non-workers']['wage'] = "0" # set wage to "0"
data['people']['citizens']['non-workers']['id'] = "2 of 2"  # set id to "2 of 2"
```

Depending on the usage, you could technically do this and create that exact example as well:

```
data = {
   "people":{
      "Citizens":{
         "Workers":{
            "wage":"34",
            "id":"1 of 2"
         },
         "non-workers":{
            "wage":"0",
            "id":"2 of 2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```